# Ignoring style preferences, is there any advantage to having one beefy loop vs many lightweight loops?

Tags: algorithm, performance, runtime

For example, is there any *practical*<sup>1</sup> performance differences between the following in any language:

```
for i=1 to 10:
    print i
for i=1 to 10:
    print i
for i=1 to 10:
    print i
for i=1 to 10:
    print i
for i=1 to 10:
    print i
```

versus

```
for i=1 to (10 * 5):
    print i%10
```

Obviously the task would typically be less trivial, but the point remains. If you have to iterate over a data set is there any advantage to doing all operations on that data in one pass versus repeatedly looping through the set?

1: I understand that there might be costs associated with repeatedly reallocating space. However, if the time is insignificant compared to any real life task then let's disregard it for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **it depends**:

- Depending on the actual task performed, readability might be improved by one approach over the other.  This is a practical issue affecting correctness and maintainability. **This should be you main concern.**
- Breaking down a large loop in smaller ones may increase cache efficiency.  But cache sizes are rather large nowadays.
- Breaking down the large loop into smaller ones may produce simpler expressions, as is obvious in your example, or fewer tests.  You might see a improvement in the for the multiple loop case, but so small it should not be a compelling reason.
- Combining small loops into a larger one may yield fewer comparisons and jumps, as is the case in your example, for a tiny improvement.  But for your example, unrolling the small loops completely might be even more advantageous.

As always, for performance tuning, you have to perform benchmarks and compare timings for actual data.  Unless you see a big improvement, choose the simplest, most readable and maintainable solution.  Note that optimality is a temporary situation, any changes in the environment, technology, data quantity and characteristics may impact the performance of any solution.